# Why does my code not work but also not have any errors?

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

> so theres no error and no issue but just wont change the json file? heres the code:

````
@client.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def points_give(member: discord.Member, amount:int=None):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        await add_experience(users, member, amount)

async def add_experience(users, member, exp):
    with open('users.json', 'r')as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        users[member.id]["experience"] += exp```
````

Comment: i was told to put ctx as the first param but that also doesnt work. no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
async def points_give(member: discord.Member, amount:int=0):
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    await add_experience(users, member, amount)

async def add_experience(users, member, exp):
    users[member.id]["experience"] += exp
    with open('users.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.load()` reads the file stream and returns a dictionary.
If you want to change the value in the file then you need to open the file in write mode and use `json.dump()` to rewrite the file.

```
with open('users.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(users, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues.

First your `async def add_experience(users, member, exp):` already takes a parameter users. But you open the json file again and load the user anew.

Second you never write your added experience back into the file. So you update the experience point and forget about it as soon as you execute on of the two functions because you never write it back.

Maybe you had a typo in the 2nd function and didn't want to read the file anew and instead write the points back into the json?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some error in opening the file. its better to use try/except in your code. Then if there is an error, you can see that.

```
def Check(file):
    try:
      open(file, "w")
      return 1
    except IOError:
      print ("Error: File does not exist.")
      return 0
    Except:
      print ("Error")
      return 0
```

In your def:

```
result = Check("yourFileName")
if (result == 1):
      #Do what you want
```

To add to json data:

```
dict = {key_value_to_be_added}

with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data.update(dict)
with open('filename', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: If it’s not too much of a bother could you directly edit it because I’m having a hard time uderstanding

Comment: the answer given by Mixno is exactly what i said. i just explain another way to debug your code, when working with files. using that is optional.